# expanding javascript(ES6) arrow notation (shorthand) to full syntax?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax, ecmascript-6

I am relatively new to javascript and ive been learning React. I followed a few tutorials for fetching data from an API in React using fetch(). The tutorial worked fine of course, and when recreating it with a different API it took me hours to figure out how to reproduce it even copying the shorthand code, so I've been trying to expand this code, so I can understand exactly what is going on.

```
fetch(request)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => { 
        let drinkNames = data.data.map(
            (dataSelect) => {
            return (
                <div key={dataSelect.data}>
                {dataSelect.name}
                </div >
            )
        })
        this.setState({drinks:drinkNames});
    })
```

That is theshorthand code and it contains what would seem like embeded functions that return other functions, but when trying to expand it everything I try gives me an error, and I would like to understand what is going on. Can anybody help me expand that code?

I read from the documentation that in its basic use, the arrow function returns whatever is in brackets. Following that logic, i tried

```
then(function(data){

        function longhand(){
            let drinkNames = data.data.map(
            (dataSelect) => {
                return (
                    <div key={dataSelect.data}>
                    {dataSelect.name}
                    </div >
                )
            })
        }

        return longhand();
```

This obviously doesnt work, and it seems there is another shorthand arrow function inside my new longhand() function, so I'm overall a bit confused. help?

Comment: what are you trying to expand and what error are you getting? Just a tip, start work/testing using an online tool like codesandbox or codepen, it allows you to easily share you're code and helps us to understand what you want to do

Comment: thanks, I will try to do so then. I am trying to expand the content inside of .then(data => ... up until before "this.setState({drinks:drinkNames})"

The code works, but I can't quite grasp how it's working which is why i want to expand

Comment: You want to render react inside a Promise result, this is not allowed. React components should always be rendered synchronously. You can use `setState` to pass data to the render function of component. Like I said, please create an example project on codesandbox. There are plenty starter projects.

Comment: arrow functions do not have their own `this` - rather, `this` is the `this` of the enclosing execution context - if you want to properly expand es6+ to es5, use a transpiler, like babel. Note, however, that small snippets of code "out of context" will result in code that isn't quite right, especially regarding `this`

Comment: I made the codesandbox file like you suggested but the issue there is the API im connecting to is not https so it's failing to fetch. Here it is anyway though if you wanna see the full code even if it won't render. The code itself does work though, I'm just tryinng to expand it so i can decipher what is going on :/ -> the codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/j34rk6pyq3

Comment: Hey @xunux, do you mind marking the answer as accepted?

Comment: yes i'd be happy to thanks so much, but im trying to figure out how to accept the answer haha im new to stackoverflow account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arrow functions expand in the following manner:

`then(data => data.id)`

is equal to:

```
then(function(data) {
    return data.id
});
```

So, your original code in ES5 syntax would look like this:

```
fetch(request)
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json()
    })
    .then(function(data) { 
        let drinkNames = data.data.map(function(dataSelect) {
            return (
                <div key={dataSelect.data}>
                    {dataSelect.name}
                </div >
            )
        })
        this.setState({drinks:drinkNames});
    })
```

**UPDATE:**

As it was correctly mentioned in the comment the context of `this` will change, as arrow functions unlike regular functions don't create their own context. Without seeing your entire component I couldn't tell you with a 100% certainty what `this` will change to, however I suspect that it will be Window or undefined.
You can always use `Function.prototype.bind` to explicitly tell the function what `this` should refer to.

Comment: this is almost right, except the `this` in `this.setState` will be either `undefined` or the *global object* (which of those it is will depend on other factors) - technically, if you want identical functionality, you should add `var _this = this` before the fetch, and use `_this.setState`